# Is it safe to shoot off a thread using async and go out the scope of its future?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a function that needs to do some immediate work (reallocate) and then some background work(move old data), can I just do this?

```
auto fof = std::async(std::launch::async, &cont2::move_data, this, old_data, old_size);
```

Seems to be working fine but I'm suspicious since it won't let me use std::async normally without something to hold the return value and tries to do the task on the same thread instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the return value, a `std::future`, goes out of scope, its destructor will halt the execution of the thread until the asynchronous operation completes.

That means that yes, if you don't return a result it will behave synchronously; the call to `std::async` will return a temporary, that will have it's destructor called immediately and block until the work is done. Similarly, if you bind it to a value, it will continue to do work, but pause once the bound value reaches the end of its scope.

For example:

```
{
    // bind to a value
    auto fof = std::async(std::launch_async, 
                          &cont2::move_data, this, old_data, old_size);
    // do work
} // at this point, execution will halt until cont2::move_data finishes
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async.

Comment: Please note that this behavior is abnormal for `future` objects. It only applies to `future`s returned by `async`. Because God forbid that C++ make sense...